# In php, are $y = $&x and $y =& $x the same?

Tags: php

In php, which of the following are the same & different

```
 $y = $&x 

 $y =& $x 

 $y = & $x;

 $y = &x;
```

It seems obvious from the behavior that some are the same, but it's not obvious if there are any hidden differences.

Comment: Yes.  Spacing doesn't matter between operators.

Comment: `$&x`, `&y`, and `&x` are syntax errors.  The rest are the same.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP,

```
 $y = &x
```

means "reference to constant x" (which is invalid and nonsense), and

```
 $y =& $x
```

means "reference to variable $x" and thus are not the same!

In general, it is a good idea to write constants in upper case, so as to make it clearer that you are not referring to a variable.

Edit2:
According to the edited Q:

Spaces are irrelevant as others posted.

Order matters: `$&x` is a syntax error.

`& $x` is uncommon syntax, better: `&$x`.

Comment: There's nothing like 'reference to constant' in PHP.

Comment: Yes, I know, but thats the "meaning" of the expression above. Leading to an error obviously. I don't know whether this is a typo of OP or the real code ... :/

Comment: Typo of OP. I expanded the question, to still include the typo.